# Are this textures?

Tags: android, imageview, textures

Now my app looks like this

[What I did http://i56.tinypic.com/6577zd.png](http://i56.tinypic.com/6577zd.png)

(it is a image set as background and an ImageView. Every time the ImageView is touch, the background is changing, so the person is "rotating"). How can I mach some regions from image to look like this:

[image: What i Want]

Are this textures? I mention that there areas are changing when the person is rotating (background is changed)...so this means that the dimension of this images is changing every time the ImageView is touch.

Any idea is welcome. Now I am block here and i don't know what to do.

Comment: It's been 2 hours since you've started this question and despite edits it still doesn't make any sense at all. No pictures are showing and the text is utterly meaningless without them.

Comment: You don't see the pictures? This is strange, because Adil Soomro edited my question and the pictures are ok. I don't understand why you don't see them

Comment: If other people can see them then I retract my complaint! It might just be my PC.

Comment: http://i56.tinypic.com/6577zd.png and this is the second
 http://i56.tinypic.com/2dipm3m.jpg

Comment: thanks george...this are the links of photos, if you can't see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compose your image by adding semi-translucent layers.

You can achieve that easily with any 2D API or with OpenGL, just use any ARGB colour model and set the Alpha channel to 50% for example, then and paint over with the rectangles.

About the positioning, that is something that you should work out by yourself, depending on how the image is changing. If you have a small set of images, maybe the easiest way is to record the hand-generated coordinate mappings in some configuration file; otherwise you'll need to deal with some nasty image-recognition problems...