# Draw a rectangular over an image by code

Tags: android, draw

I have this xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/photo0"
    android:id="@+id/imagBackground">

    <TextView android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dip" android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/index" android:text="0" android:textColor="#000000">
        </TextView>

        <ImageView android:layout_marginTop="280dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/anim_ctrl_panel" android:id="@+id/change">
        </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and over this I must draw some rectangular by code. How to do this ?

I tried this :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagBackground);
        changeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.change);
        index = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.index);

        draw();
    }

        private void draw() {
        System.out.println("desenam");
        int width = 50;
        int height = 100;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawRect(25, 50, 75, 150, paint);
         ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);


        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

         layout.addView(imageView);

        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

but the rectangulars are on the bottom on screen. How to set the location where to put them?

Comment: Using the `drawRect` API :), you are setting the left to 25 and top 50, right 75, bottom 150. Change this to change your location of your rectangle..

Comment: I set this dimension (25,50,75,150) but on screen it is not like this...this is the problem..I need to set the rectangle over the image that is set as background

Comment: did you try adding the imageview to the layout first and then drawing the rectangle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is, the reason why it's in the bottom of the page is because of the LinearLayout: in the end you will have 3 children: TextView, ImageView and ImageView, all below each other.

A few possible solutions:

1. Add a FrameLayout inside the LinearLayout and add the ImageViews inside it, so the hierarchy would be:

   - LinearLayout

     - TextView
     - FrameLayout

       - ImageView
       - ImageView
2. Use a RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayout and align all the edges of the second ImageView with the first one
3. Create a custom ImageView class, for example "com.foo.bar.MyImageView", which of course extends ImageView. Override onDraw:

   ```
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas); // This will render the original image
       // ... and here you can have the code to render the rectangle
   }
   ```

In the xml you replace

```
 <ImageView ...
```

with

```
 <com.foo.bar.MyImageView ...
```

I would go for the last solution, since from a performance point of view it's the best.

Comment: if I will use first or second solution, can I set a imageView created by code over an imageview that is on xml? For last solution, do you know an example to help me?

Comment: I mention that I must put many image, it must look like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808009/are-this-textures

Comment: Yes, you can have ImageView created from code over ImageView created from xml. There is no difference on where they were created. The important thing is the layout: they must be layouted at the same position.

Comment: You can have as many rectangles as you want, but if you use solution 1 or 2 (i.e. create an extra ImageView), then create ONLY ONE ImageView for all the rectangles, and not one for each. I don't have any ready made example for solution 3, but it's simple, just try it out: a) create a new class which is a subclass of ImageView, replace ImageView in the xml with that class (don't forget to add the package name as well). At this point verify that the image is still visible. If yes, proceed: override onDraw and just draw something there, after calling super.onDraw(canvas).

Comment: for solution 3, all the imageview that I create will be at the same position? I don't want this, as you can see at the link I posted.

Comment: or I must set a imageView on xml for every image created on onDraw() method?

Comment: In solution 3 there would be only one ImageView. It would render the background picture (via super.onDraw) and then you need to render the rectangles wherever you want and as many as you want.

Comment: ok, now I try. I put <com.www.MyImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.www.MyImageView> on xml file but I get ForceClose. The ImageView class is: public class MyImageView extends ImageView{

 public MyImageView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  System.out.println("draw");
 }

}

Comment: on xml the class MyImageView is not visible.

Comment: the problem was the constructor. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
        Point left=new Point(x, y);

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00CCFF"));
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(left.x, left.y, 9, paint);
```

So you have to create a Point using pixels and then draw a rectangle around it otherwise it doesn't know where to draw

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do this in the layout file itself:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/photo0"
android:id="@+id/imagBackground">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"              android:background="@android:color/black">
<TextView android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dip" android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/index" android:text="0" android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:layout_marginTop="280dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/anim_ctrl_panel" android:id="@+id/change">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain a little? Do you mean to use a linearlayout over the principal linearlayout ?

Comment: Nothing. It will just create a LinearLayout with "black" background on top of a linearlayout with "draker gray" background or any other color you want. But the black linearlayout will have a margin of any size. Like in the above code the layout_margin is "5dip".This will create a rectangular area around your main linear layout.

Comment: I think this is not a solution for me...I must do something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808009/are-this-textures

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `LinearLayout` to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="top" android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/photo0"
    android:id="@+id/imagBackground">
...
```