# How to create a Rect using an image?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am creating a rect using coordinates of image, but the same image place in 10 times in different locations. My use is to stop another rect when touch the image rect.  So I will create 10 rects . Is any way to create image as a rect . Please help me.

Edit:I am asking It is possible to create image as a rect. That image I will place in different locations, rect will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna write code here but I prefer that offer other links for you.

I hope these is useful for you:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832838/draw-a-rectangular-over-an-image-by-code), [link2](http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/graphics-basics.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response what I am asking It is possible to create image as a rect. That image I will place in different locations, rect will work or not.

Comment: why do you do? do you have several images or a image that can move?

Comment: same image place different locations at a time, not move.

Comment: I don't test it but I think not problem. you should create several images and set their position.

Comment: I am creating single image rect and place different positions,that image perform as rect in each position.How it is possible.